# Programmatically Detect Context Switch via Assembly

Tags: c, windows, assembly, kernel

I am aware that one cannot listen for, detect, and perform some action upon encountering context switches on Windows machines via managed languages such as C#, Java, etc. However, I was wondering if there was a way of doing this using assembly (or some other language, perhaps C)? If so, could you provide a small code snippet that gives an idea of how to do this (as I am relatively new to kernel programming)?

What this code will essentially be designed to do is run in the background on a standard Windows UI and listen for when a particular process is either context switched in or out of the CPU. Upon hearing either of these actions, it will send a signal. To clarify, I am looking to detect only the context switches directly involving a specific process, not any context switches. What I ultimately would like to achieve is to be able to notify another machine (via the internet signal) whenever a specific process begins making use of the CPU, as well as when it ceases doing so.

My first attempt at doing this involved simply calculating the CPU usage percentage of the specific process, but this ultimately proved to be too course-grained to catch the most minute calculations. For example, I wrote a test program that simply performed the operation 2+2 and placed the answer inside of an int. The CPU usage method did not pick up on this. Thus, I am looking for something lower level, hence the origin of this question. If there are potential alternatives, I would be more than happy to field them.

Comment: You need to provide more information about what you want. Where would this code run, and when?

Comment: C++ is not a managed language.

Comment: I have addressed both of these concerns now.

Comment: You do realize that these context switches can happen a thousand times per second... And that sending a signal is itself a context switch! What is this signal supposed to do? You haven't yet described the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I'm looking for context switches pertaining only to a specific process (when that process is context switched in or out), not any old context switch. The problem I'm trying to solve is to send a signal when the process is context switched in, and then another when it is switched out, and so on.

Comment: The app can get context switched in and out thousands of times a second. For example, writing a pixel to the screen is two context switches. What do you intend to do with this signal?

Comment: I've added some more hopefully helpful detail.

Comment: This sounds very much like you've decided how to solve the problem based on an incorrect assumption. There should be no need to detect context switches - What are you actually trying to achieve? Let the remote machine know if the process has done _any_ execution in a given timespan? Detect resource usage as closely as possible or ??? As others have said, detecting switches themselves will cause _more_ switches and will ultimately bog the machine down - Think of the frequency of the cpu, do you _really_ need to count potentially millions of switches per second? If so, I'd love to know why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the edits below. In particular #3, ETW appears to be the way to go.

In theory you could install your own trap handler for the old `int 2Eh` and the new `sysenter`. However, in practice this isn't going to be as easy anymore as it used to be because of Patchguard (since Vista) and signing requirements. I'm not aware of any other *generic* means to detect context switches, meaning you'd have to roll your own. All context switches of the OS go through call gates (the aforementioned trap handlers) and ReactOS allows you to peek behind the scenes if you feel uncomfortable with debugging/disassembling.

However, in either case there shouldn't be a *generic* way to install something like this without kernel mode privileges (usually referred to as ring 0) - anything else would be a security flaw in Windows. <s>I'm not aware of a Windows-supplied method to achieve what you want either.</s>

The book "Undocumented Windows NT" has a pretty good chapter about the exact topic (although obviously targeted at the old `int 2Eh` method).

If you can live with hooking only certain functions, you may be able to get away with some filter driver(s) or user-mode API hooking. Depends on your exact requirements.

*Update:* reading your updated question, I think you need to read up on the internals, in particular on the concept of IRQLs (not to be confused with IRQs from DOS times) and the scheduler. The problem is that there can - and usually will - be literally hundreds of context switches every second. However, your watcher process (the one watching for context switches) will, like any user-mode process be preemptable. This means that there is no way for you to achieve real-time signaling or anything close to it, which puts a big question mark on the method.

What is it actually that you want to achieve? The number of context switches doesn't really give you anything. Every single SEH exception will cause a context switch. What is it that you are interested in? Perhaps performance counters cater your needs better?

*Update 2:* the sheer amount of context switches even for a single thread will be flabbergasting within a single second. So assuming you'd install your own trap handler, you'd still end up (adversely) affecting all other threads on the system (after all you'd catch every context switch and then see whether it's the process/threads you care about and then do your thing or pass it on).

If you could tell us what you *ultimately* want to achieve, not with the means already pre-defined, we may be able to suggest alternatives.

Update 3: so apparently I was wrong in one respect here. Windows comes with something on board that signals context switches. And ETW can be harnessed to tap into those. Thanks to Simon for pointing out.

Comment: I would only like the context switches pertaining to one specific process, and I'm not looking to count them - I'm looking to perform some action upon their occurrence. Would this also be on the order of hundreds per second?

Comment: @JohnRoberts: yes, it very likely still would be that order of magnitude. Many common operations end up in the kernel, be it various types of registry access, file access or access to all kinds of kernel objects such as events, mutexes and semaphores. It's unlikely you'd be able to do anything meaningful "right after" such an event without somehow (spin locks?) blocking everything else that goes on.

Comment: `int 2Eh` and friends are not helping here and unrelated. They are just used for syscalls and are not called upon preemption. It's just one reason for a context switch, out of many. As Alexey Frunze correctly answered, ETW is the way to go.

Comment: @Simon: tell me where I wrote that preemption has anything to do with `int 2Eh` and friends, please! I didn't and I wouldn't. However, whether you can react *timely* to a context switch that you "sensed" through a custom trap handler has to do with whether your code can be preempted. Please re-read my answer. Side-note: how ETW is supposed to help is beyond me. Because ETW requires always an active part that **supplies** the event that you want to listen to. I'm not aware of one for the context switches, though. Pointing to ETW without details won't help.

Comment: Here's how ETW is related to context switches: http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/05/11/the-lost-xperf-documentationcpu-scheduling/

Comment: Cool, now I get what you are up to. Thanks for the link.

Comment: I will look into ETW and the CSwitch class. I am entirely new to these concepts however, so even the tiniest example of CSwitch in action would be immensely helpful, as it seems fairly complex from what I've so far researched (as well as devoid of practical examples).

Answer (score 4):

There's [Event Tracing for Windows (ETW)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968803%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which you can configure to receive messages about a variety of events occurring in the system.

You should be able to receive messages about thread scheduling events. The [CSwitch class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964744%28VS.85%29.aspx) of events is for that.

Sorry, I don't know any good ETW samples that you could easily reuse for your task. Read MSDN and look around.

[Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/742404) pointed out a good link explaining why ETW can be useful. Very enlightening: http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/05/11/the-lost-xperf-documentationcpu-scheduling/

Comment: The performance monitor in Visual Studio might be useful and/or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/performance/cc825801.aspx .